# The statement or command was not processed because the following clause is not supported in the context where it is used "WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP"

Tags: sql, database, db2

Databse: DB2

I am trying to alter default column value with the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE branch ALTER COLUMN brn_score SET DEFAULT 10;
```

but I get the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: The statement or command was not processed because
> the following clause is not supported in the context where it is used:
> "WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP".. SQLCODE=-109, SQLSTATE=42601,
> DRIVER=4.26.14

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Db2 on which OS platform and what version? How do you run the statement, from CLI, from a tool or ...?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, I'm using DBeaver (v. 21.1.1) for running the statement.

Comment: Which version of Db2?

Comment: BTW: It seems that more than the shown statement was sent to Db2.

Comment: DB2 version: 11.1.4.4

Comment: @AhsanAli Could you provide a reproducible example like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/cwgSDonQ) one, which works without errors?